# Maven local dependency isn't working: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, netbeans, dependencies, local

I have a Maven Web project made in netbeans and I have a local dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
        <optional>true</optional>            
    </dependency>
```

That dependency works perfectly if I run the project over Apache Tomcat 6.0 but I have some class that I run on demand (main method) and when I try to run the class I get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: You used optional which means it is not part of the packaged artifact. This artifact is installed in your Tomcat...

Comment: @Shiradit Why Are you using a system path for the dependency? I think that the Class Loader is not able to find the class. Can you share your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it works for me)

1. Get rid of the maven dependency, and the jar from the lib (we'll have it automatically added)
2. From your project, right click on the "Dependencies" -> "Add Dependency"
3. In the dialog, type the coordinates for the groupId, artifactId, version, click ok
4. This will leave an unresolved jar in the dependency tree.
5. Right click on the jar from the "Dependencies", select "Manually Install Artifact". Locate the artifact and add it, and "Install Locally". This will install the jar to the local repo. Also since its a webapp, the jar will get sent to the `lib` like it normally would

Now you should be able to run it.